# Books recommended for Regression modeling and probability

Tags: regression, probability, references, modeling, inference

Hi I m the student of  Msc statistics and I find it really tough to clear concepts regarding modelling, distributions ,inference etc.
 Can anyone recommend some best books in all these subjects which are totally conceptual and containing practicals based on  real life..

Comment: See [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references?sort=votes&pageSize=30) for related requests. You might find what you need.

Comment: Could you make your question more concrete, give some details?

Comment: "infrance"---do you mean inference? Please edit!

Comment: "Modeling, distributions, inference, *etc*" is too broad for us to handle: it sounds like all of statistics (plus some science and philosophy thrown in).  If you have a specific request, please search our site first, because there are many threads with recommended texts.  Then, if you do not find a suitable answer, you may edit this post to focus it on what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Statistical Inference, George Casella, Roger L. Berger. This is one of the most commonly used book for masters level probability and statistics. I have used it, that consists of many examples describing them well.  You can even find the pdf version of that. 
Also, "Mathematical Statistics" by I.Miller and M.Miller is another graduate text with lots of examples describing the distributions well.

Answer (score 0):

Frank Harrell Jr's Regression Modeling Strategies, second edition.

The book is easy to read, filled with examples and practical advice.

Comment: Anyone for probability distributions and infrance

Comment: I will let others comment on that.

Comment: For probability I recommend you:

A First Course in Probability (Sheldon Ross)
Introduction to probability theory (Paul G. Hoel)
Introduction to the theory of Statistics (Mood and Graybill) _Actually, this book have both, probability and statistics topics._

About regression I'd consider Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis (Douglas C. Montgomery)